# why does this error appear when installing ns2 on fedora 24?

Tags: c++, linux, gcc

I am trying to install ns2.35 on my fedora 24 and after installing all lib and when I install the application, this problem appears:

> configure: WARNING: unrecognized options: --enable-gcc
>       checking whether to use symlinks for manpages... no
>       checking whether to compress the manpages... no
>       checking whether to add a package name suffix for the manpages... no
>       checking for gcc... gcc
>       checking whether the C compiler works... no
>       configure: error: in '/home/mohammad/Documents/ns-allinone-2.35/tcl8.5.10/unix':
>       configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
>       See `config.log' for more details
>       tcl8.5.10 configuration failed! Exiting ...
>       Tcl is not part of the ns project.  Please see www.Scriptics.com
>       to see if they have a fix for your platform.

Comment: "See `config.log' for more details".

Comment: This Q is not about programming as defined for StackOverflow. It **may** be more appropriate on the S.E. related sites  http://unix.stackexchange.com  (Unix & Linux) or http://superuser.com.  Use the `flag` link at the bottom of your Q and ask the moderator to move it. Please don't post the same Q on 2 different sites. Please read  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask and http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve before posting more Qs here. Good luck.